# Name of this Data Structure?

Tags: c++, data-structures

So I recently came across a data structure roughly like this:

```
template<class T>
struct Node {
    size_t m_next;
    size_t m_prev;
    T m_key;
}

template<class T, size_t N>
struct DS {
    Node<T> m_elements[N];
    size_t m_head;
    size_t m_tail;
}
```

I simplified a bit, just to keep this brief: I don't do error handling when `DS` gets too full. Normally `N` is large enough that this isn't a concern.

One note is `T` must have some way of representing "no value"; why this is needed can be seen below. (I'll refer to this value as `TOMBSTONE` below.)

The API for this data structure is roughly the same as for a linked list, but it performs much better because everything fits nicely in the cache.

The actual implementation is different from a linked list in that it doesn't need to allocate any new memory for new nodes. For example, pushing to the back of `DS` is roughly like this:

```
void DS::push_back(T t) {
    size_t attempt = 0;
    size_t i = hash(t, attempt++);
    while (true) {
        if (m_elements[i] == TOMBSTONE) {
            m_elements[m_tail].m_next = i;
            m_elements[i] = Node(N, m_tail, t);
            m_tail = i;
            break;
        }
        i = hash(t, attempt++);
    }
}
```

where `hash(T t, size_t attempt)` finds places to try to insert new elements. (This is so there's nice spread, rather than clumping everything at the start.)

I hesitate to call this a linked list because of the vast performance and implementation differences from a normal linked list. I also want to point out that this question is not about *when* to use what data-structures, or if the above data-structure is good/fast/safe/whatever. This data-structure works quite well for us in the very specific situation we use it in.

Is there any name for this particular implementation/data-structure?

Comment: Linked hash table?

Comment: Seems like a regular linked list that uses a pool of preallocated nodes.

Comment: Nodes that refer to other nodes in the same list is a linked list. In this case, a double-linked list. The links are simply using indexes instead of pointers, but they are still links nontheless.

Comment: What are you using this data-structure for? It should have fast lookup and delete, but I don't think the performance will be much better than that of a well-implemented hash-set (unless you needed fast transversal of a very sparse hash-set)

Comment: Also, hashing seems to be unnecessary here. You can allocate and destroy nodes in the array in O(1) time and O(n) memory. (Not sure how exactly the algorithm for that is called, but I have an implementation [lying around](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/imp-re/blob/master/src/utils/resource_allocator.h))

Comment: On a side note: "*One note is `T` must have some way of representing "no value"*" - sounds like a job for `std::optional<T>`, or maybe `std::variant<T, nullptr_t>`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen we just call it a `List`, but since it's used and performs quite different from a normal linked list I was hoping there was a special name

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez It's used for objects in a game. They die and are created quite often, and we need to traverse them quite quickly. There were lots of implementations we used and benchmarked, and (one similar to this one) ended up being the best.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, hashing is not really needed here, it's just to get a good spread throughout the array.

Comment: Dynamic allocation is not essential to a linked list. The links are.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, if I were going for a general purpose version of this, I'd certainly do that. In our particular case, there's sensible "empty" values we use, but your suggestion is certainly cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

It is linked list. It's mentioned on Wikipedia as ["Linked list using arrays of nodes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Linked_lists_using_arrays_of_nodes)

Comment: I was hoping for a better name but I guess there isn't any

Answer (score 1):

It's a double-linked linked list, implemented with a C-style array.